# error in ngrok - failed to complete tunnel connection

Tags: linux, localhost, ngrok

So I just wanted to create some phishing websites to try them out but now whenever I try to create one via ngrok or just start ngrok `./ngrok http 80` and then visit the site it shows me this -

> **Failed to complete tunnel connection**
> The connection to https://xxx.xxx.ngrok.io was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client, but the client failed to establish a connection to the local address localhost:80.
> Make sure that a web service is running on localhost:80 and that it is a valid address
> **the error encountered was: dial tcp [::1]:80:Connect:connection refused.**

and also google shows a warning to these whenever I visit them
any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You should create a local server on port 80 . Use **php** or **python** to create a local server .

**PHP**

```bash
~$ php -S localhost:80
```

**Python**

```bash
~$ python -m http.server 80
```

After starting the local server open a new terminal session and start ngrok

```bash
~$ ./ngrok  http 80
```

You can create a  link with `ssh` also  .make sure that you have installed ssh.

```bash
~$  php -S localhost:80 | ssh -R 80:localhost:80 ssh.localhost.run
```

or

```bash
~$  python -m http.server 80 | ssh -R 80:localhost:80 ssh.localhost.run
```

By the way chrome will automatically detect the phishing pages.

Comment: nothing seems to work , the website says - the request was not found on this server and the terminal- GET / favicon.io    404 not found

Comment: Have you login to your ngrok account `./ngrok authtoken [YOURAUTHTOKEN].here is the link https://ngrok.com/

Comment: yeah i already did it

Comment: You can do this just run `ssh-keygen` and generate a ssh key.Install python and run `python -m http.server 80 | ssh -R 80:localhost:80 ssh.localhost.run` now you will see a link. If want to use ngrok try the command in above answer.make sure that your are running command prompt/terminal as  administrator/superuser privilege

Answer (score 0):

Check your console. Due to some error, your connection might be getting closed. Due to which ngrok is not able to complete the tunnel connection.